# Replacing soft RAID1 LUKS disks with larger ones

Tags: debian, hard-disk, raid, luks

I am planning to replace two soft RAID1 disks (2TB) with two identical (4TB disks). The current disks are configured with soft RAID 1 running debian 11. The disks are not root.

My plan is to replace (hot swap is supported) one 2TB disk with a new 4TB disk and wait for the disks to sync with mdadm (I'm not even sure how to do that but I guess I'll Google it). Once the sync is over I am planning to do the same hot swap with the remaining 2TB disk replacing it with the other new 4TB disk and wait for mdadm to finish to sync.

At this point, I will still (hopefully) find myself with two LUKS disks with 2TB partitions that I need to enlarge. This operation is a pain in the ass but I have done it before on my laptop, but never with a RAID1 configuration.

1. Do you think my plan makes sense?
2. Can you give some guidance on how to enlarge a RAID 1 LUKS partition (that is, the last step of my plan)?
3. Is there any other smarter option?

As per request in the comments, here's the output of `lsblk`:

```
root@server:~$ lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0    0   3.6T  0 disk  
`-sda1         8:1    0   3.6T  0 part  
  `-md4        9:4    0   3.6T  0 raid1 
    `-4tb    253:1    0   3.6T  0 crypt /media/4tb
sdb            8:16   0   3.6T  0 disk  
`-sdb1         8:17   0   3.6T  0 part  
  `-md4        9:4    0   3.6T  0 raid1 
    `-4tb    253:1    0   3.6T  0 crypt /media/4tb
sdc            8:32   0 119.2G  0 disk  
`-sdc1         8:33   0 119.2G  0 part  
  `-md127      9:127  0 119.2G  0 raid1 /
sdd            8:48   0 119.2G  0 disk  
`-sdd1         8:49   0 119.2G  0 part  
  `-md127      9:127  0 119.2G  0 raid1 /
sde            8:64   0 465.8G  0 disk  
`-sde1         8:65   0 465.8G  0 part  
  `-md0        9:0    0 465.6G  0 raid1 
sdf            8:80   0   2.7T  0 disk  
`-sdf1         8:81   0   2.7T  0 part  
  `-3tb      253:2    0   2.7T  0 crypt /media/3tb
sdg            8:96   1 931.5G  0 disk  
`-sdg1         8:97   1 931.5G  0 part  
  `-md1        9:1    0 931.4G  0 raid1 
    `-vm     253:3    0 931.4G  0 crypt /media/vm
sdh            8:112  1   1.8T  0 disk  
`-sdh1         8:113  1   1.8T  0 part  
  `-md2        9:2    0   1.8T  0 raid1 
    `-backup 253:0    0   1.8T  0 crypt /media/backup
sdi            8:128  1 931.5G  0 disk  
`-sdi1         8:129  1 931.5G  0 part  
  `-md1        9:1    0 931.4G  0 raid1 
    `-vm     253:3    0 931.4G  0 crypt /media/vm
sdj            8:144  1   1.8T  0 disk  
`-sdj1         8:145  1   1.8T  0 part  
  `-md2        9:2    0   1.8T  0 raid1 
    `-backup 253:0    0   1.8T  0 crypt /media/backup
```

Comment: Linux allows stacking various storage features on top of each other in any order. Based on your description, I'm not sure if the LUKS layer is "above" or "below" the RAID layer in your setup. This is going to affect the order of operations you'll need to do. Could you please add a `lsblk` listing from your system to your question? You can censor the names of the mountpoints and such if you wish; I would just like to see if it's disk->part->raid1->crypt or disk->part->crypt->raid1.

Comment: Since you're not booting from these disks, you could do without any partitioning whatsoever. Just fail (say) `/dev/sdb1` and replace it with the new 4 TB `/dev/sdb`, then similarly for the other disks. This way you needn't enlarge any partitions, just `mdadm --grow` and `cryptsetup resize` afterwards. Even if you want/need to keep the partitions, create them with their final size, and add those to the RAID; component devices are allowed to be larger than necessary. And for maximum safely, add the new device(s) before removing the old ones if you can to ensure redundancy throughout the change.

Comment: I added in the question the output of lsblk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your `/media/*` mounts seem to use the disk->part->raid1->crypt layering.

Note that if your existing 2 TB disks are partitioned in MBR style, you can't really do that with the new larger disks, as you'll be hitting the MBR maximum capacity limit. Fortunately, Linux software RAID does not require you to have the same type of partitioning on the individual halves of the RAID set (or in fact, with non-boot disks, you would have the option of not using any partitioning scheme at all).

So, assuming that `md2` is the RAID set you wish to migrate to the larger disks, and you'll want to swap `sdh` first:

1. Mark `sdh1` as a failed RAID1 component: `mdadm --manage /dev/md2 --fail /dev/sdh1`
2. Remove it from the `md2` RAID set: `mdadm --manage /dev/md2 --remove /dev/sdh1`
3. Tell the kernel that the disk will be hot-unplugged: `echo 1 > /sys/block/sdh/device/delete`. Depending on the controller and the disk model, the disk may or may not actually spin down as you do this.
4. Physically replace the `sdh` disk with a new one.
5. Find out the new disk device name (it may or may not be `/dev/sdh`; let's call it `sdX`).
6. If you wish to use partitioning, use GPT partitioning type and create a single partition that covers the whole disk. Set the partition type to "Linux RAID" (GPT partition type GUID `A19D880F-05FC-4D3B-A006-743F0F84911E`; most GPT partitioning tools have some more user-friendly way to specify that.) This partition will be bigger than the existing half of this RAID set; this is entirely fine at this point. `mdadm` will only use as much as needed to mirror the `sdi1` partition until you'll give it permission to use the full capacity in step #10 later.

(If you use partitioning, you may want to use some specific size instead of just using the disk in full, in order to guard against the possibility that you might need to replace the disk in the future and might not be able to source replacement disks with the exact same number of blocks. Then again, future disks are likely to be bigger than the current ones, which would make this a non-issue.)

7. Add the new disk to the RAID set. If you partitioned the disk, use `mdadm --manage /dev/md2 --add /dev/sdX1`; if you decided to use the whole disk as unpartitioned RAID device, use `mdadm --manage /dev/md2 --add /dev/sdX`.
8. Monitor `/proc/mdstat` to see when the synchronization is complete.
9. Repeat steps 1-8 for the second disk `sdj`.
10. When both disks have been replaced and are in sync, use `mdadm --grow /dev/md2 --size=max` to allow the `md2` RAID device to fully use the increased capacity.

(If you chose not to use partitioning in step #6 above, you could also use a specific size instead of `--size=max` here, for the same reason as in step #6.)

11. Once the `md2` device has been successfully resized, use `cryptsetup resize /dev/mapper/backup` to resize the encrypted device on top of the `md2` RAID set.
12. Finally, resize the filesystem on top of the encrypted device, with either `fsadm resize /dev/mapper/backup`, or by using a filesystem-specific tool (`resize2fs /dev/mapper/backup` for ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem types, `xfs_growfs /media/backup` for XFS, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for the extremely exhaustive and very clear answer. This weekend I will give it a try!

Comment: Thank you so much it worked!!!! I even swapped the two 2TB hard drives with 2 1TB veeeery old hard drives (1 years old I think, is it possible?)

Comment: Meant to say 10 years old :)