# Mismatch in disk size between lsblk and df

Tags: debian, hard-disk, raid, mdadm, software-raid

I have recently upgraded two soft raid1 2TB disks with a set of two 4TB raid 1 disks.
(see [Replacing soft RAID1 LUKS disks with larger ones](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678484/replacing-soft-raid1-luks-disks-with-larger-ones/678868#678868))
The guide was amazing, however I find myself with two different results in their size and I don't know whether to believe `df -h`.

Please focus on the drives `/dev/mapper/backup` aka `/media/backup` aka `md4`

```
root@SRVR:~$ df -h
Filesystem          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                 13G     0   13G   0% /dev
tmpfs               2.6G  888K  2.6G   1% /run
/dev/md127          117G  8.3G  103G   8% /
tmpfs                13G  4.0K   13G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/mapper/4tb     3.6T  2.3T  1.2T  67% /media/4tb
/dev/mapper/3tb     2.7T  855G  1.8T  33% /media/3tb
/dev/mapper/vm      1.8T   97G  1.7T   6% /media/vm
/dev/mapper/backup  1.8T  1.5T  238G  87% /media/backup
```

or believe `lsblk`:

```
root@SRVR:~$ lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0    0   3.6T  0 disk  
`-sda1         8:1    0   3.6T  0 part  
  `-md4        9:4    0   3.6T  0 raid1 
    `-4tb    253:1    0   3.6T  0 crypt /media/4tb
sdb            8:16   0   3.6T  0 disk  
`-sdb1         8:17   0   3.6T  0 part  
  `-md4        9:4    0   3.6T  0 raid1 
    `-4tb    253:1    0   3.6T  0 crypt /media/4tb
sdc            8:32   0 119.2G  0 disk  
`-sdc1         8:33   0 119.2G  0 part  
  `-md127      9:127  0 119.2G  0 raid1 /
sdd            8:48   0 119.2G  0 disk  
`-sdd1         8:49   0 119.2G  0 part  
  `-md127      9:127  0 119.2G  0 raid1 /
sde            8:64   0 465.8G  0 disk  
`-sde1         8:65   0 465.8G  0 part  
  `-md0        9:0    0 465.6G  0 raid1 
sdf            8:80   0   2.7T  0 disk  
`-sdf1         8:81   0   2.7T  0 part  
  `-3tb      253:2    0   2.7T  0 crypt /media/3tb
sdg            8:96   1   1.8T  0 disk  
`-sdg1         8:97   1   1.8T  0 part  
  `-md1        9:1    0   1.8T  0 raid1 
    `-vm     253:3    0   1.8T  0 crypt /media/vm
sdh            8:112  1   3.6T  0 disk  
`-sdh1         8:113  1   3.6T  0 part  
  `-md2        9:2    0   3.6T  0 raid1 
    `-backup 253:0    0   3.6T  0 crypt /media/backup
sdi            8:128  1   1.8T  0 disk  
`-sdi1         8:129  1   1.8T  0 part  
  `-md1        9:1    0   1.8T  0 raid1 
    `-vm     253:3    0   1.8T  0 crypt /media/vm
sdj            8:144  1   3.6T  0 disk  
`-sdj1         8:145  1   3.6T  0 part  
  `-md2        9:2    0   3.6T  0 raid1 
    `-backup 253:0    0   3.6T  0 crypt /media/backup
```

and believe as well `mdadm`:

```
root@SRVR:~$ mdadm -D /dev/md4
/dev/md4:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Tue Oct 20 00:17:12 2020
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 3906885440 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 3906885440 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Fri Dec 10 16:00:12 2021
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : GC01SRVR:4  (local to host GC01SRVR)
              UUID : 18dfa172:e97bd6ce:9e379633:0e8a0f28
            Events : 57617

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: /media/backup is /dev/md2 and it seems like you forgot to grow the filesystem

Comment: Aaaaaaand that was the answer! Write the answer so I can mark it solved if you can be bothered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my guess is that lsblk report free blocks in the devices, where df report part of the filesystem used.

to be sure of the structure of your different software RAID you should provide a view of the `/proc/mdstat`  like

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

and then compare with

```
lvs -o +devices
```

to ensure yourself that the right volume is related to the right RAID device. If there still present a difference it might be because the filesystem used on the device is not (yet) adapted to the device like if you have forgotten to extend or resize the filesystem according to the new device size. You can do this with the right tool depending what filesystem you are using.
commonly for ext family filesystem you can use

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/backup
```

whereas for xfs you should use xfs_growfs

```
xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/backup
```

btrfs or zfs have their own command to resize, I let you check regarding what is your filesystem.